# angularjs what is the best way to rewrite span <span> as anchor <a>

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, anchor

I have a problem where I retrieve a string with  elements in them, I need to rewrite them a  elements.  The values I need are in attributes of the  element.
e.g.

```
<div>The way to find your answer is to go to <span rel="webResource" resource="http://www.stackflow.com">Stack Flows Home</span> webpage.</div>
```

I had done it in JQuery with a technique like:

```
jQuery.fn.makeA = function() {
    var attrs = {};
    $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
         attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.value;
    }
    this.replaceWith(function() {
          var jqThis = $(this);
          return $(document.createElement("a"))
                      .attr("href", encodeURI(jqThis.attr("resource")))
                      .attr(attrs)
                      .append(jqThis.contents());
    }); 
}
```

and then doing this to the string:

```
var element = $(spanText);
$("span[rel='webResource']",element).makeA();
return (element[0].outerHTML);
```

Since I have had to create a Custom Directive in AngularJS for this, is there a good way while in the directive code to implement the same technique without JQuery?

Well, some progress..
I created a customer directive for handling the insertion of the original string:
`.directive('displayString'...)`
and then after reading this: [http://blog.timsommer.be/using-compile-to-compile-html-strings-in-angular/], I recognize that doing an element.html(databaseString) will render correctly in the browser, but I needed to use $compile to get the string to be fully "jammed" into the DOM.  Once I added the $compile, like Tim Sommer suggested!, the .directive('rel'...) is now firing!  But, when the .directive gets the compiled  the element value is now "empty", e.g.: 
`<span rel="webResource" resource="http://www.stackflow.com">Stack Flows Home</span>` is now `<span rel="webResource" resource="http://www.stackflow.com"></span>` 
Interestingly, the $compile actually triggers the 'rel' directive immediately and it runs before the next statement in the 'displayString' executes.

Any idea why the value/text of the  has gone missing?
So, progress, but still stuck!

Comment: Would your directive be on the `span` or on the `div`?

Comment: `span`. Actually, I have a version that was `.directive('rel', [function(){...})`, hanging a custom directive on a standard attribute seemed like a bad idea.

Comment: Well, some progress... Reading this: [http://blog.timsommer.be/using-compile-to-compile-html-strings-in-angular/}, I recognize that doing an element.html(databaseString) will render correctly in the browser, I needed to use $compile to get the string to be fully "jammed" into the DOM.  Once I added the $compile, like Tim Sommer suggested!, the .directive('rel'...) is now firing!

Comment: [ng-transclude](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24725520/1795795) might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

It takes two directives.

1. $compile in the first directive to deal with the retrieve HTML from the database and also to **trigger** the pushing of the HTML elements in the answer text into the DOM…
2. `transclude:yes` AND the use of `template` with the `ng-transclude` directive and use of {&} in the scope variable, so Angular knows to hold onto the contents of the fact string’s embedded s (and Angular does NOT like the ng-transclude directive in the strings passed to $compile!) and replace the value of the href from the specific context.

Putting a directive on `@rel` is very dangerous, because it’s a standard RDFa property and is used with  and  HTML instructions.  However, with the guard conditionals it’s ok.

```
app.$module.directive('displayFact', ['$compile', function($compile){
   return {
      restrict: 'E', 
      scope: { fact : '@'},
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var templateInASense = $compile('<span>' + scope.fact + '</span>')(scope);  // this triggers the 'rel' directive below, <span> is required to allow $compile to deal with it..
            element.replaceWith(templateInASense);
          }
}}]);
```

and directive 2:

```
app.common.$module.directive('rel', [function(){
 return {
    restrict: 'A', 
    scope : { reference : '&'},
    transclude: true,
    template: '<span><a href="{{reference}}" target="_blank"><span ng-transclude /></a></span>', 
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (typeof attrs.resource !== "undefined") {
                   scope.reference= attrs.resource; 
            }
          }
}}]);
```

The snippet of the Template HTML looks like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="fact in list"><display-fact fact={{fact.label}}></display-fact></td>
```

That seems to work pretty well.  It handles multiple s in a single string.  And it seems pretty quick.