# ng-transclude in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

According to the definition of Transclusion in angular.js "**With transclude enabled, anything that exists inside the welcome element in the view will be appended to the contents of whichever element in the template has the ng-transclude attribute.**", I was trying to understand following behavior:-

```
<html>
 <head>
<title>AngularJS Services</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="abc.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <tab>
            hello world
    </tab>
</body>
</html>
```

Angular Code:-

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp',[]);


function tab(){

  return {
    restrict : "E",
    transclude: true,
    template: '<h2 ng-transclude>Hello world!</h2>\
               <div role="tabpanel" ng-transclude>kickass</div>',
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope,element,attrs){}

  };


};

myApp.directive('tab',tab);
```

Now if u give `ng-transclude` inside `h2` tag the contents under `h2` are getting destroyed, however when I give `ng-transclude` in div it works fine. Transclusion here according to definition says that the values would be appended to anything between the tags. Please collect me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'd use a stable version of Angular before going any further with this. Why use a beta for an older version?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/Io4zCEKrb6YLYQQgQXll?p=preview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is ng-transclude?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725399/what-is-ng-transclude)